# Python: is there a way to permanently change a variable from another Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables, python-3.5

Is there a way to permanently change a variable, so it does not reset when the code finishes? I have this code:

variables.py:

```
myvar = None
```

Main.py:

```
import variables
variables.myvar = True
```

Get_variable.py:

```
import variables
print(variables.myvar)
```

Output:

```
None
```

I want it to print `True`

Comment: "Is there a way to permanantly change a variable, so it does not reset when the code finishes? " No, *the variable no longer exists when the code finishes*. Generally, you are talking about data persistence. This can be achieved with something as simple as a file, but could mean some query to some database server.

Comment: Putting all random unrelated variables in one file is a bad idea to begin with. You may zant to rethink your strategy.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain please?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can change the file:

```
fin = open("path-to-variables.txt","a")
fin.write("myvar = True")
```

That should change the actual file.

Comment: You _can_, but you shouldn't use a .py file for variable persistence.

Comment: Gee I hope there’s nothing else in that file you just wiped ...

Comment: Come now. Obviously you would use separate file for each variable. :)

Comment: I put pribily earlier, I mean probally

Comment: It should work. But yeah, this isn't the most elegant way of doing it. Technically, you shouldn't store variables out of your file if you are gonna modify them.

Comment: It is used in multiple files, and I want them to all see the same thing from the file

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible (without re-writing the entire python script in the second script to write the entire thing back to file), but there's another way to do this. Instead of storing variables in a python script, you can store variables in another type of file, like a json. You could have "variables.json":

```
{ "myvar": null }
```

then in your python:

```
import json         # import the json library

with open("variables.json", "r") as f:      # read the json file
  variables = json.load(f)

myvar = variables["myvar"]    # To get the value currently stored

variables["myvar"] = True    # change the variable in python

with open("variables.json", "w") as f:      # write back to the json file
  json.dump(variables, f)
```

If you have a lot of variables, you can store them all in json as with a dictionary:

```
{ "onevar": null,
  "twovar": "kittens",
  "redvar": "foo",
  "bluevar": "bar" }
```

FOR OPENOFFICE WRITER:
Since you're writing all of this in OpenOffice on a Raspberry pi, and having trouble creating the json file yourself (open office assumes it's a writer document), you can simply allow python to create it:

```
import json

variables = { "onevar": null,
              "twovar": "kittens",
              "redvar": "foo",
             "bluevar": "bar" }

with open("variables.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(variables, f)
```

If python is told to open a file to write, and the file doesn't exist, python should create the file in question, unless it's told to create it in a directory that doesn't exist (so, you couldn't say open("myfolder/variables.json", "w") if the directory "myfolder" didn't exist). You can run this once to init your json file, and then go on opening and closing from there.

Comment: It wouldn't save as .json, I typed in variables.json as the name, due to no json in the dropdown, and it saved as variables.json.otd

Comment: That's new to me. How are you running the python code? No json in the dropdown of what? Did you import json?

Comment: LibreOffice Writer, I am using HATs on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Ah, I'll add to my answer.